# Symfony2 AngularJS Unable To Remove web/app_dev.php

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I have a Symfony AngularJS app and I've hosted it on a VPS. I installed Symfony using softalicious which did a good job of making it run quickly.

**Where I'm at right now**

http://website.com/web/app.php shows:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@website.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

http://website.com/web/app_dev.php works

Everytime I try to remove the web/app_dev.php, I start getting the above error.

**I have tried the following**

- Changed DocumentRoot to web/
- Added RewriteBase / to the project root .htaccess
- Added RewriteBase /web/ to the web folder .htaccess
- Added RewriteBase / to the project root .htaccess
- Added RewriteBase /web/ to the web folder .htaccess

Earlier http://website.com/web/app.php also worked, but one of the above or maybe something else has made it start throwing the 500 internal server error.

I had a default .htaccess in project root and web folder I'm attaching it as follows for reference (it's not too big, most of it is comments):

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE**

error_log file today shows:

```
[Sat Feb 13 05:47:28 2016] [error] [client 27.251.209.122] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sat Feb 13 05:47:29 2016] [error] [client 27.251.209.122] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://website.com/
[Sat Feb 13 05:47:29 2016] [error] [client 27.251.209.122] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://website.com/ the limit if necessary.
[Sat Feb 13 05:53:06 2016] [error] [client 27.251.209.122] SoftException in Application.cpp:355: UID of script "/home/website/public_html/web/app.php" is smaller than min_uid
[Sat Feb 13 05:53:06 2016] [error] [client 27.251.209.122] Premature end of script headers: app.php
```

Hope this helps debug the problem.

**UPDATE**

I tried removing the .htaccess file from the project root and I get the following:

```
.git/
.gitignore
LICENSE
README.md
UPGRADE-2.2.md
UPGRADE-2.3.md
UPGRADE-2.4.md
UPGRADE-2.8.md
UPGRADE.md
bin/
cgi-bin/
components/
composer.json
composer.lock
composer.lock.orig
composer.lock.rej
composer.phar
notindex.php
source/
vendor/
web/
```

So my .htaccess is what is causing the problem. Isn't it?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: app.php switches to production mode which won't show you errors.  you'll want to check the apache logs and show us what errors that produced

Comment: and this is tagged with `angularjs` because?

Comment: @Kstro21 because thats what the app uses and could be the reason behind the error. Considering it's a question, I don't exactly know what could be causng the problem

Comment: @JasonRoman for some reason the log files a not being updated, I have seen both, apache and app/logs, while dev.log publishes some warning for using depriciated classes. No new errors are being published.

Comment: Where are you checking log files?  Something like /var/log/apache2 ?  There should be some record of the error

Comment: Just to be sure... did you clear cache?

Comment: @JasonRoman I am checking /etc/httpd/logs/error_log

Comment: Definitely check other areas for the logs, like the folder I described...or depending on what OS you're on, look up where the standard error log folder is for Apache

Comment: I'm on CentOS. The only log files I have are in /etc/httpd/logs/error_log which had errors but they were few weeks old about an error during development, which I have already fixed. To easily identify and publish the errors here, I cleaned the error_log file and opened app.php hundreds of times till now, still the same server error 500, yet the log stays empty.

Comment: @Pipe Sorry I missed your comment in between, yes I have surely cleared cache in production environment.

Comment: @JasonRoman Hi Jason, I have pasted the error_logs above. Please let me know if you've faced this problem before. I'll try my luck on Google in the meanwhile. Thanks again.